# GGplot2 plots and dataTables having conditionalPanel suddenly disappeared in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am new to shiny dashboard.  I was making few data tables and plots in shiny session. It was working fine two days ago. All the output was working perfectly for last 2 days.
I had used global functions to for the  the plot and tables and called them from within the shiny server with appropriate reactive elements. It worked fine.

But when suddenly something went wrong when revisited my work  for final checks and the plots and data tables now show up as just blank , the select menu options do not display any more. I am in sort of panic now as this was an assigned task to me and I have a deadline.

All the conditional panel related work has mostly disappeared and syntax wise everything looks fine. I am using 2 files system for the dashboard with some conditionalPanels , Tabitems and tabPanels.

Please help!! And guide me what possibly could have gone wrongs so that I can do the checks.

Thanks.

Comment: Cool down and see here: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: Have a look at the console output, those lines after `shiny::runApp(...)`. Check for error messages, it might all boil down to a missing parenthesis or similar.